# template() in Handlebar.js not accepting parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, handlebars.js

So, this is the code:

```
$('li.list').on('click', function(){
    console.log(this.id); 
    var temp = template(library) ; 
    console.log(temp); 
    $('.infotemplate').append(temp);
});
```

When I logged this.id, it gives me the correct id i.e. library. but when I pass that into template() function it does not parse the details of my object library. But when I explicitly pass the library as a parameter in function(), it gives the correct output.
So, I want this dynamically, that when a user clicks on that id, the object of same name as that of id gets appended later in body.

```
$('li.list').on('click', function(){
    console.log(this.id); 
    var temp = template(this.id) ; 
    console.log(temp);
    $('.infotemplate').append(temp);
});
```

How do I solve this? Please help..

Comment: can you show how do you set library variable in above code? and if you add the html that would be helpful

Comment: Library is an object in javascript:

var library = {
  icon: 'library',
  title: 'Things to Learn',
  desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor'}

and its also the id of element which when click should load this object in the template.

Comment: Oh, I have already declared var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#template').html() );

Where #template refers to the handlebars template code.

Comment: can you show the #template html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a variable for each item, create an object with all of them and use the `id` to access them from that variable..

What you are currently doing is passing the string **library** and not the variable with that name..

```
var items = {
   library : {icon:'..', title:'...',..},
   cityhall: {..},
   ...
}
```

And use

```
$('li.list').on('click', function(){
    console.log(this.id); 
    var temp = template(items[this.id]) ; 
    console.log(temp);
    $('.infotemplate').append(temp);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I just used eval() to convert it to an object, and so it worked! :D 3 hours just passed banging my head.

Comment: Well then how do I convert that string to object without making the main master object?